# How to use and IF statement in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using the expression below in PHPMYADMIN with the intent to use it later in a PHP/MySQL application. It gives an error relating to the DECLARE statement in line 1.

I've looked at example declarations in MySQL and I don't see an error, but I'm doing something wrong and would appreciate a correction/suggestion.

BEGIN DECLARE searchresult int(11); SET searchresult=(Select count(*) from wbsimsynuqsql where SimBase='a cappella'); IF searchresult >0 THEN Select * from simsyn1sql where BaseID = (Select Distinct BaseID from wbsimsynuqsql where SimBase='a cappella') ELSE Select * from simsyn1sql where BaseID = (Select Distinct BaseID from wbsimsynuqsql where SimSyn='a cappella')

END IF; END

I would appreciate suggestions/corrections.

Thank you.

Comment: "It gives an error relating to"... This weakens your question.  Please edit to include the exact error received.

Comment: Please [edit] and format your code properly. [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Since this is a code related question, it should be moved to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)